# Laptop overheating

Tags: fancontrol

I have a Toshiba L500-128 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit OS,
the only problem I have is the overheating of my CPU, with temperatures from 70 to 90 C.

I think that this is related to the usage of the CPU fan. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try cleaning the laptop, in particular intake and output from the fan. You can try using a different kernel and if the problem resolves it would likely be a bug.

Comment: Are you using a manufacturer approved battery in the unit?

Comment: http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/satellite-l500-128/ install ATI drivers

Comment: then use this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

First of all that's nothing to worry about.  I would though agree with `bodhi.zazen`, in trying to clean the laptop.  I would recommend getting a can of compressed air, and try to clean the CPU fan.  Now according to Intel, that CPU, is rated at 105°C. See [Here](http://ark.intel.com/products/39311/).  So 70°C to 90°C to is OK, and it should drop down once the CPU fan is cleaned.

Comment: at 55 to 58 fan start kicking ( loosing battery ), 60 to 65 More , 70 ++ fan get mad running on full speed ...( eating battery )

Answer (score 0):

Unless the system shuts down, then it isn't overheating.  Those temperatures are normal when under load.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases fan speed is calculated at boot time, so try to wait the laptop to heat a bit, then restart it.
The fan speed will be, hopefully, recalculated and the problem solved, since the microprocessor is never too cold.
I'm not joking, try it!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try installing the [proprietary graphics driver](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx).

   I had the same issue with the free drivers (some version of ubuntu ago), I saw great change after changing to the official (proprietary) drivers.
2. Cleaning the cooling system of your laptop will definitely really improve the situation. Dust and hair form a thick "blanket", not allowing the air pass. The laptop must be opened. Check if it is in warranty. If it is not, you may open it. Check for the service manual or relevant videos on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I had a toshiba with similar issues. What I discovered was that it wasn't always the cpu, but the gpu. You usually feel the heat on the left side of the hand rest area of the keyboard. After a LOT of research, I discovered that it was an issue with the DSDT - Toshiba doesnt generate their own for their laptops, so Microsoft ends up producing the DSDT file used on the system. I was able to rectify by decompiling the DSDT and making some manual changes to it and recompiling it, then, added it back to the linux boot loader and that fixed it.

If you want to, research DSDT files and their relationship to system hardware controls - especially regards to regulating the fan.

Comment: Could you provide instructions for accomplishing this? As it stands, this isn' t really a good answer.